# it is possible to use keyof to update object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, keyof

i want to implementation a function to update object like this.

```js
interface Object {
   name: string
   age: number
}

let obj = {}

function updateObject(key: keyof Object, value: ???) {
   obj[key] = value;
}
```

It is possible in typescript? and what i should input at `???`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics to say that `key` is a key of `Object` and `value` is the type of that key

```
interface Object {
   name: string
   age: number
}

let obj: Object = {};

function updateObject<K extends keyof Object>(key: K, value: Object[K]) {
   obj[key] = value;
}

updateObject('name', 'foo'); // Fine
updateObject('name', 1); // Error
updateObject('age', 'foo'); // Error
updateObject('age', 1); // Fine
```